# How to config route.rb when locale is sub-directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-i18n

I tried to configure localize setting on RoR.
Even though I set up along with guide below, it doesn't work correctly.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

Here's my code. Here's simple restaurant list.

application_controller.rb

```
  before_action :set_locale

  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
  end

  def default_url_options(options = {})
    { locale: I18n.locale }.merge options
  end
```

routes.rb

```
 # Locale Information
scope "(:locale)" do
  resources :restaurants
end

  # Example of regular route:
get 'restaurant/list' => 'restaurant#list'
get 'hello/index' => 'hello#index'
```

And results are here.

```
Routing Error
No route matches [GET] "/en/restaurant/list"
```

Comment: Check output of rake routes. I wonder if the get 'restaurant/list' => 'restaurant#list' should go into the scope.

Comment: Without scope declaration, it works. 
http://example.com/restaurant/list
works correctly. The thing is that trying to put locale on the url like above doesn't work.

Comment: @sethi Thanks for the comment. I finally got what you mean. See my following answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining a non restful route (list) outside your scope, but not inside. If you need to stick to 'list', you should define it inside your scope as well:

```
# Locale Information
scope "(:locale)" do
 resources :restaurants do 
  get :list, on: :collection
 end
end
```

Then go to localhost:3000/en/restaurants/list and you should have it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But still doesn't work. The result is same.

Comment: Note that it is not /restaurant/list anymore, but restaurants, plural

Comment: Still same. Accessing `http://localhost:3000/en/restaurants/list` and `http://localhost:3000/en/restaurants/`arrose both same error.

How should I do?

Comment: Mercelo, thanks the comment. I got fixed it at last. I owe you.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I fixed it following all the comments. The final route.rb is like this.

```
scope "(:locale)" do
   get 'restaurant/list' => 'restaurant#list'
end
```

I appreciate all.